# AWS - Autoscaling not launching/killing instances as specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I'm testing the AWS autoscaling. I've created a simple elastic beanstalk and edited the scaling settings. Here's a screenshot of the auto scaling group scaling policies:

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to get the group to have between 5 and 10 healthy instances in permanence. The max and min number of instances have been set to 20 and 2.

I only get 2 instances (the minimum) running.

The alarms are defined as:

- ping-server-too-healthy
  [image]
- ping-server-not-healthy-enough
  [image]

The Load Balancer's alarms seems to be working correctly:

[image]

But the scaling group is not booting new instances. I've tried settings the alarms the other way around (I'm not sure they are triggered when they go from true to false or from false to true) and that leads to 20 instances (the maximum)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is **not** the way that you should be using Auto Scaling.

When Elastic Beanstalk creates a **"Load balancing, auto scaling"** environment, it creates the Auto Scaling group for you. As part of these configurations, you can specify the **minimum** and **maximum** number of instances to launch in the Auto Scaling group:

[image: Elastic Beanstalk auto scaling configuration]

The Auto Scaling group will then keep the current **Desired Capacity** of instances within the minimum and maximum. If an instance fails (definition below), Auto Scaling will automatically replace that instance with another one to **maintain the Desired Capacity**.

The **Scaling Policies** are then used to **adjust the Desired Capacity**. Scaling policies should use some measure of "load" to determine when to add or remove instances, such as CPU Utilization or the size of an Amazon SQS queue. The intention is to add additional servers when more capacity is required, and remove servers when there is too much capacity.

The `HealthyHostCount` metric indicates how many servers have passed the Elastic Load Balancing **health check**. If an instance fails the health check, the Load Balancer stops sending it requests, but keeps performing the health check. If the instance becomes healthy again, the Load Balancer will resume sending requests to that server. The Elastic Load Balancing health check can be configured to check a particular page on the server to confirm that the **application is healthy**.

**When Auto Scaling performs a health check**, it is merely [checking the the status of the virtualization environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html), in the same way that the EC2 management console shows `2/2 status checks`. However, it is possible to **configure Auto Scaling to use the Elastic Load Balancing heath check**. This way, Auto Scaling can be notified that the **application** is unhealthy and can automatically replace a failed instance (or an instance with a failed application).

You stated that your goal is *"to get the group to have between 5 and 10 healthy instances in permanence"*. This is the job of Auto Scaling, especially when it has been configured to use Elastic Load Balancing health checks. The job of a scaling policy is to determine when to add/remove instances based upon workload. **Scaling policies should not be used as a means of replacing unhealthy instances.**

So, I recommend:

- Configure a **Health Check** in your Load Balancer that accurately checks the health of your application
- Turn on **ELB health checks** in your Auto Scaling group (which will ensure that instances with unhealthy applications will be replaced)
- Use **Scaling Policies** to add/remove instances based upon **workload** rather than based on health
- Trust the system. It works!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I think you're right about the poor design choice detailed my question, and that ultimately the scaling should be dependent on the application health. I set up those scaling policies to test the scaling behavior because they are easier to test in a staging env than workload based ones. However, should not the current setting lead to a scaling between 5 to 10 instances? I'd like to understand and test the alarms/scaling policies mechanics well before moving to trusting the system! And currently that mean getting a group of 5-10 instances :)

Comment: You can manually trigger scaling policies via the console ("Execute"). But if you want a *real* test of the system, your scaling policies should be based on load, so you'll have to generate load somehow.

Comment: "Execute" scales up or down as excepted. I'm unsure the alarms are working correctly since they should be triggered, and automatically trigger the scale up and down. I think currently it's trying to remove instances, and hits the lower limit. If I revert the alarms, it goes to 20 (the upper limit) showing that alarms did get trigger, but not with the right logic

Comment: @JohnRotenstein could you please elaborate more on this point "Turn on ELB health checks in your Auto Scaling group (which will ensure that instances with unhealthy applications will be replaced)"? Where exactly in "Configuration" can I control this setting?

Comment: @littleibex Please ask a new Question rather than asking questions as comments on old questions. (BTW, it is a setting in the Auto Scaling group. I'm not sure if it is a setting in Elastic Beanstalk directly.)